# generic order in c# for a lists

Tags: c#, generics

I  have a class in c# called CarFabric and i have a list car like this:

```
public class CarFabric
{
List<Car> cars;
(..other methods..)

}
```

the thing is, my cars have two ways the buyers would like to order them: By price and by model. I would like to order the list by one of them depending on what the user selects, overall, a generic method that orders my list either by price or model, depending on the user.

**SOLVED**

This solved my problem by using the *Strategy*  design pattern as described here http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern implementing in different classes the following.

`cars.OrderBy(c => c.Price)` or `cars.OrderBy(c => c.Model)`

as suggested in comments.

Thanks!

Comment: `cars.OrderBy(c => c.Price)` or `cars.OrderBy(c => c.Model)`

Comment: Sometimes you get your answers in the comments

Comment: that i dont know why does not work, it does not recognize c as a car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a LINQ query to sort the elements without touching the concrete list.

```
var result = cars.OrderBy(car => car.Price);
```

or

```
var result = cars.OrderBy(car => car.Model);
```

Comment: Does the list know that car is an actual car? cause that is not compiling. And i dont want to save the return of that

Comment: Well... I don't understand your question. The list is typed for Car, so, what else would it be? Can you take a print or paste your code in dotnetfiddle.com entry, so I'll be able to understand?

Comment: public class Fabrica : IFabrica
    {
public List<Pedido> pedidos { get; set; }

public void OrdenarPedidoPorFecha() 
        {
              //i should order here the list by date
        }
}

@dmyoko

Comment: and doing pedidos.OrderBy(pedido => pedido.Date); does not work 
@dmyoko

Comment: I suppose pedido.Date is a DateTime value, ok?

Comment: you are correct, its actual name is pedido.fechaEntrega and its a date time. The problem is that it does not appear any of the propertys of pedido but it recognize it as an object, do i need to cast it?

Comment: i had a problem with the visibility of them and i did not know that default attributes were private, added the public visibility to the attribute and worked, thank you very much! sorry for the time loss